# In hive, can a php custom reducer include another php file?

Tags: hive

Let me explain the actual problem using a very simple dummy problem.
Input: 
1 2
3 4

Output :
1 4
9 16

I would write a custom reducer process.php which will read every line and square the numbers. But the square function is readily available in some other file lets say utils.php Can I not do something like 
require_once('utils.php') in process.php

Hive query would look like this :

```
FROM (
  SELECT num1, num2 FROM input
)aa
SELECT TRANSFORM(num1, num2)
USING 'process.php' as num1,num2   ;
```

I have tried it doing on Amazon AWS infrastructure. No success. There is no documentation about this.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I found the fix to problem. "require_once" is indeed allowed in a reducer script but there is a catch.

Let me name the files for clarity ...

reducer script : **reducer.php**

required file : **utils.php**

**Case 1**: reducer.php and utils.php are in same folder 
Simply require_once('utils.php') works.

**Case 2**: reducer.php and utils.php are in different folder 
Lets say paths are A/reducer.php and A/B/utils.php
Again, simply require_once('utils.php') works. require_once('B/utils.php') is not needed, in fact require_once('B/utils.php') doesn't work.

Reason: all files added via 'add file' end up in the same directory on the mapper/reducer.